# How can send an email with Laravel 5.4 with Mail facade

Tags: php, laravel, email

I created a form to send an email. I created an email file named 'ContactMailFull' with the command `php artisan make:mail ContactMailFull`.

Here is my file

```
class ContactMailFull extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $name;
    public $subject;
    public $email;
    public $description;


    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->name        = $request->input('name');
        $this->subject     = $request->input('subject');
        $this->email       = $request->input('email');
        $this->description = $request->input('description');
    }


    public function build()
    {

        return $this->view('mails.sendFull')
                    ->subject($this->subject)
                    ->from('guess@gmail.com', 'Guess')
                    ->with([
                        'name' => $this->name,
                        'subject' => $this->subject,
                        'email' => $this->email,
                        'description' => $this->description
                    ]);
    }
}
```

I try to send the email but But it's not right. I know we have to do something like this.

`Mail::to('my-email@gmail.com')` with a `New Something` But I do not understand the documentation. And I do not know where I have to put it.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5.3 & 5.4 introduced the concept of [Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail).

You have done 90% of the job. You just need to send the e-mail now using `Mail` facade.

```
Mail::to('john@example.com')->send(new \App\Mail\ContactMailFull($request));
```

Also, you don't explicitly need to pass the variables to the view. The public properties `name`, `subject` etc will become available to the view by default.

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail) under `via Public properties`

Comment: Thank you @Mozzammil, and where I put the "Mail::to" ? In my controller ?

Comment: That depends on your application, but wherever you need to take the action to send the email, yes. So if it is within your controller, sure.

Comment: You can use  `Mail::to` , from where you are sending email